# Friggeri Resume template: problem of having several nested items inside an entrylist

Tags: lists, cv, friggeri-cv

I am using Friggeri Resume/CV template, which can be found [here](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/friggeri-resume-cv). I have a problem in adding items to an `entrylist` which has several nested items.

To replicate the problem, I have added 21 of the following item to an `entrylist` in the work experience section:

```
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine
```

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{friggeri-cv} % Add 'print' as an option into the square bracket to remove colors from this template for printing

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib} % Specify the bibliography file to include publications

\begin{document}

\header{john}{smith}{junior business analyst} % Your name and current job title/field

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SIDEBAR SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{aside} % In the aside, each new line forces a line break
\section{contact}
123 Broadway
City, State 12345
Country
~
+0 (000) 111 1111
+0 (000) 111 1112
~
\href{mailto:john@smith.com}{john@smith.com}
\href{http://www.smith.com}{http://www.smith.com}
\href{http://facebook.com/johnsmith}{fb://jsmith}
\section{languages}
english mother tongue
spanish \& italian fluency
\section{programming}
{\color{red} $\varheartsuit$} JavaScript
Python, C++, PHP
CSS3 \& HTML5
\end{aside}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{education}

\begin{entrylist}

%------------------------------------------------

\entry
{2011--2012}
{Masters {\normalfont of Commerce}}
{The University of California, Berkeley}
{\emph{Money Is The Root Of All Evil -- Or Is It?} \\ This thesis explored the idea that money has been the cause of untold anguish and suffering in the world. I found that it has, in fact, not.}

%------------------------------------------------

\entry
{2007--2008}
{Bachelor {\normalfont of Business Studies}}
{The University of California, Berkeley}
{Specialization in Commerce}

%------------------------------------------------

\end{entrylist}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   WORK EXPERIENCE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{experience}

\subsection{Full Time}

\begin{entrylist}

%------------------------------------------------

\entry
{2012--Now}
{LEHMAN BROTHERS}
{Los Angeles, California}
{\emph{1\textsuperscript{st} Year Analyst} \\
Developed spreadsheets for risk analysis on exotic derivatives on a wide array of commodities (ags, oils, precious and base metals), managed blotter and secondary trades on structured notes, liaised with Middle Office, Sales and Structuring for bookkeeping. \\
Detailed achievements:
\begin{itemize}
\item Learned how to make amazing coffee
\item Finally determined the reason for \textsc{PC LOAD LETTER}:
\begin{itemize}
\item Paper jam
\item Software issues:
\begin{itemize}
\item Word not sending the correct data to printer
\item Windows trying to print in letter format
\end{itemize}
\item Coffee spilled inside printer
\end{itemize}
\item Broke the office record for number of kitten pictures in cubicle
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 01
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 02
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 03
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 04
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 05
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 06
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 07
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 08
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 09
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 10
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 11
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 12
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 13
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 14
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 15
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 16
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 17
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 18
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 19
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 20
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 21

\end{itemize}}

%------------------------------------------------

\end{entrylist}


\end{document}
```

The output is shown in the following two pictures. As can be seen, having many items will leave a lot of white spaces in the first page. How can I distribute all the items in both first and second page of the document? My resume needs to have similar number of items that is shown in this MWE. Could someone help me fix this problem?

**First page:**

[image: First page]

**Second page:**

[image: second page]

Comment: You are out of luck. `entrylist` uses a `tabular*` which can never break across pages.

Comment: Try with this in your preamble: `\usepackage{enumitem}
\renewenvironment{entrylist}{%
  \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1in]}{%
  \end{itemize}
}
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\headingfont\color{headercolor}}
\renewcommand{\entry}[4]{%
  \item[#1]
    \textbf{#2}%
    \hfill%
    {\footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray} #3}\\%
    #4\vspace{\parsep}%
  }
%-------`

Comment: It kind of works except that the spacing is not matched with the rest of the document.

Comment: The spacing between items in the list.

Comment: You can change that with `enumitem` `begin{itemize}[itemsep=<whatever you want>]`

Comment: Fantastic. Worked just fine.

Comment: Dear Harish. Thanks. I appreciate it if you would.

Comment: Please use a zero spacing between the items in the list.

Comment: Use `\begin{itemize}[noitemsep]`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `entrylist` environment and `\entry` command are defined like this in `friggeri-cv`:

```
\newenvironment{entrylist}{%
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}
}{%
  \end{tabular*}
}
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\headingfont\color{headercolor}}
\newcommand{\entry}[4]{%
  #1&\parbox[t]{11.8cm}{%
    \textbf{#2}%
    \hfill%
    {\footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray} #3}\\%
    #4\vspace{\parsep}%
  }\\}
```

A deadly combo of `tabular*` and `\parbox` and none of these allow page breaks. Hence your only option is to re-define them like

```
%------------
\usepackage{enumitem}
\renewenvironment{entrylist}{%
  \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1in]%[leftmargin=*,align=left,itemindent=-\dimexpr\labelwidth+\labelindent+\labelsep\relax]
}{%
  \end{itemize}
}
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\headingfont\color{headercolor}}
\renewcommand{\entry}[4]{%
  \item[#1]
    \textbf{#2}%
    \hfill%
    {\footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray} #3}\\%
    #4\vspace{\parsep}%
  }
%-------
```

Since we are loading the `enumitem` package, you may adjust the spacing between items with

```
begin{itemize}[itemsep=<whatever you want>]
```

Adjust as suitable.

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass[]{friggeri-cv} % Add 'print' as an option into the square bracket to remove colors from this template for printing

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib} % Specify the bibliography file to include publications

%------------
\usepackage{enumitem}
\renewenvironment{entrylist}{%
  \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1in]%[leftmargin=*,align=left,itemindent=-\dimexpr\labelwidth+\labelindent+\labelsep\relax]
}{%
  \end{itemize}
}
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\headingfont\color{headercolor}}
\renewcommand{\entry}[4]{%
  \item[#1]
    \textbf{#2}%
    \hfill%
    {\footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray} #3}\\%
    #4\vspace{\parsep}%
  }
%-------

\begin{document}

\header{john}{smith}{junior business analyst} % Your name and current job title/field

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SIDEBAR SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{aside} % In the aside, each new line forces a line break
\section{contact}
123 Broadway
City, State 12345
Country
~
+0 (000) 111 1111
+0 (000) 111 1112
~
\href{mailto:john@smith.com}{john@smith.com}
\href{http://www.smith.com}{http://www.smith.com}
\href{http://facebook.com/johnsmith}{fb://jsmith}
\section{languages}
english mother tongue
spanish \& italian fluency
\section{programming}
{\color{red} $\varheartsuit$} JavaScript
Python, C++, PHP
CSS3 \& HTML5
\end{aside}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{education}

\begin{entrylist}

%------------------------------------------------

\entry
{2011--2012}
{Masters {\normalfont of Commerce}}
{The University of California, Berkeley}
{\emph{Money Is The Root Of All Evil -- Or Is It?} \\ This thesis explored the idea that money has been the cause of untold anguish and suffering in the world. I found that it has, in fact, not.}

%------------------------------------------------

\entry
{2007--2008}
{Bachelor {\normalfont of Business Studies}}
{The University of California, Berkeley}
{Specialization in Commerce}

%------------------------------------------------

\end{entrylist}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   WORK EXPERIENCE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{experience}

\subsection{Full Time}

\begin{entrylist}

%------------------------------------------------

\entry
{2012--Now}
{LEHMAN BROTHERS}
{Los Angeles, California}
{\emph{1\textsuperscript{st} Year Analyst} \\
Developed spreadsheets for risk analysis on exotic derivatives on a wide array of commodities (ags, oils, precious and base metals), managed blotter and secondary trades on structured notes, liaised with Middle Office, Sales and Structuring for bookkeeping. \\
Detailed achievements:
\begin{itemize}
\item Learned how to make amazing coffee
\item Finally determined the reason for \textsc{PC LOAD LETTER}:
\begin{itemize}
\item Paper jam
\item Software issues:
\begin{itemize}
\item Word not sending the correct data to printer
\item Windows trying to print in letter format
\end{itemize}
\item Coffee spilled inside printer
\end{itemize}
\item Broke the office record for number of kitten pictures in cubicle
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 01
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 02
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 03
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 04
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 05
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 06
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 07
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 08
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 09
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 10
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 11
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 12
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 13
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 14
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 15
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 16
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 17
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 18
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 19
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 20
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 21

\end{itemize}}

%------------------------------------------------

\end{entrylist}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For zero spacing between items, please use `\begin{itemize}[noitemsep]`

Comment: Can you please comment on how to have the same thing for `\begin{enumarate}`? Thanks.

Comment: I want to have another list environment that put number before each item in the list similar to `\begin{enumarate}`. I copied what you posted for `\begin{itemize}` but it does not work and the compiler complains.

Comment: Yes, something similar to `entrylist`.

Comment: @A2009 Put `\newcounter{mycount}\setcounter{mycount}{0}` and then in the definition of `\entry` → `\renewcommand{\entry}[4]{%
  \item[\refstepcounter{mycount}\themycount. #1]....`

Comment: @A2009: you may also play with these:  `\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,align=left,itemindent=-1in]` in `entrylist` definition.

Comment: Copy past of this wizard's code worked perfectly for me.

Comment: This works brilliantly, the only downside seems to be that the dates are now right-aligned rather than left-aligned. Is it possible to keep the original behaviour of left-alignment with this fix?

Answer (score 1):

I ended the **itemize** and **entrylist** where I wanted the page to break (for this example i did it after the item "Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 05"), and then began the entrylist, entry and the itemize again, so it would start normally on the next page, without changing any other configuration. 
It worked for all CVs I did that followed the base of the friggeri template. snippet for the page break:

```
  \end{itemize} }
  \end{entrylist}
\begin{entrylist}
\entry{}{}

  {
  \begin{itemize}
```

snippet inside full code:

```
% -- Encoding UTF-8 without BOM
% -- XeLaTeX => PDF (BIBER)

\documentclass[]{cv-style}          % Add 'print' as an option into the square bracket to remove colours from this template for printing. 
                                    % Add 'espanol' as an option into the square bracket to change the date format of the Last Updated Text

\sethyphenation[variant=british]{english}{} % Add words between the {} to avoid them to be cut 

\begin{document}

\header{john}{smith}{junior business analyst} % Your name and current job title/field

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SIDEBAR SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{aside} % In the aside, each new line forces a line break
\section{contact}
123 Broadway
City, State 12345
Country
~
+0 (000) 111 1111
+0 (000) 111 1112
~
\href{mailto:john@smith.com}{john@smith.com}
\href{http://www.smith.com}{http://www.smith.com}
\href{http://facebook.com/johnsmith}{fb://jsmith}
\section{languages}
english mother tongue
spanish \& italian fluency
\section{programming}
{\color{red} $\varheartsuit$} JavaScript
Python, C++, PHP
CSS3 \& HTML5
\end{aside}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{education}

\begin{entrylist}

%------------------------------------------------

\entry
{2011--2012}
{Masters {\normalfont of Commerce}}
{The University of California, Berkeley}
{\emph{Money Is The Root Of All Evil -- Or Is It?} \\ This thesis explored the idea that money has been the cause of untold anguish and suffering in the world. I found that it has, in fact, not.}

%------------------------------------------------

\entry
{2007--2008}
{Bachelor {\normalfont of Business Studies}}
{The University of California, Berkeley}
{Specialization in Commerce}

%------------------------------------------------

\end{entrylist}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   WORK EXPERIENCE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{experience}

\subsection{Full Time}

\begin{entrylist}

%------------------------------------------------

\entry
{2012--Now}
{LEHMAN BROTHERS}
{Los Angeles, California}
{\emph{1\textsuperscript{st} Year Analyst} \\
Developed spreadsheets for risk analysis on exotic derivatives on a wide array of commodities (ags, oils, precious and base metals), managed blotter and secondary trades on structured notes, liaised with Middle Office, Sales and Structuring for bookkeeping. \\
Detailed achievements:
\begin{itemize}
\item Learned how to make amazing coffee
\item Finally determined the reason for \textsc{PC LOAD LETTER}:
\begin{itemize}
\item Paper jam
\item Software issues:
\begin{itemize}
\item Word not sending the correct data to printer
\item Windows trying to print in letter format
\end{itemize}
\item Coffee spilled inside printer
\end{itemize}
\item Broke the office record for number of kitten pictures in cubicle
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 01
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 02
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 03
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 04
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 05
  \end{itemize} }
  \end{entrylist}
\begin{entrylist}
\entry{}{}

  {
  \begin{itemize}  
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 06
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 07
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 08
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 09
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 10
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 11
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 12
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 13
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 14
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 15
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 16
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 17
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 18
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 19
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 20
\item Learned how to make more amazing coffee on a new machine 21

\end{itemize}}

%------------------------------------------------

\end{entrylist}


\end{document}
```

[image: how it worked for this example]

[image: how it worked for a cv i was making]

Answer (score 0):

There is a janky trick here - if your Entrylist includes multiple sections, you can individually wrap each one as an independent Entrylist, and pages will correctly break between them

[image: Single Entrylist Entry, in Tabular, showing correct page break]

Comment: Welcome. // Can you please add the before and after codes to your answer. No screenshot of code, please, but code.

Comment: Style code:
```\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\newenvironment{entrylist}
{%
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}11}
}{%
  \end{tabular*}
}
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\headingfont\color{headercolor}}
\newcommand{\entry}[4]{%
  #1&\parbox[t]{20cm}{
    \textbf{#2}%
    \vspace{-0.3cm}
    \hfill%
    {\footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray} #3}\\%
    #4\vspace{.25cm}
  }\\}```

Comment: Entry code:
```\vspace{-0.3cm} %Sets space between the Header and sec. above
\section{}
\vspace{-0.25cm} %Sets space between Header and Entries
\begin{entrylist}
\entry
  {Year-Year}
  {Title, Company (Location)}
  {}
  {
  \begin{itemize}
  \vspace{-0.08cm} 
  \item Text
  \item Text
\end{itemize}}
\end{entrylist}```

Comment: Hm, the first time I see a longer code placed in the comments. What's the better place? EDIT your question, move it there, put a few more sentences to turn your answer into a stand-alone solution. Finally, delete both comments.